CPU doesn't lower the frequency when idle
I switched to AMD processors a few years back and thought I just don't know something about their power management. So, for a couple of years I've had an 5600X processor running in a PRIME B550-PLUS motherboard and it never lowered it's frequency when idling, the least I saw was 3.6GHz and mostly it was around 3.8-4.2 range. Then I switched to 5800X3D, pretty much the same story.
But then I've used the 5600X for a home server with another motherboard and what do you know, it idles at 1.7 there.
So the main PC's MB, the aforementioned Asus PRIME B550-PLUS, what bios setting should I switch to allow the lower power states? The thing is, I had the settings defaulted many times already and I would expect the default CPU mode would be as powersaving as possible, not "boosted" or fixed frequencies. Apparently that's not the case somehow. After defaulting I usually set up only the fan and boot/drive settings and don't poke around overclocking. I've googled and poked at any "C-states" and "power states" I could find but never had the CPU idling correctly at the lower states.
So what am I missing then? What's the Asus/AMD bios switch actually does that? Or may that not work because I'm using 3600MHz memory with XMP/DOCP profile?

I know in the past it was called Cool'n'Quiet but I don't know if it still is.

Check your Windows Power settings.
See what the Power mode setting (search "Power and Sleep settings" settings) is set to.
Check the specific CPU state settings - this is how I had to make it so that my CPU would not slow down at idle
I'm still running Windows 10, not sure where it would be if you are running Windows 11.
In the Power and Sleep settings window, click "Additional power settings" OR you can go through Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Power Options.
If preferred plan is not already "Power saver" you can try just switching to that.
To see what the actual processor settings are:
click "Change plan settings" for your selected preferred plan, then on Change Advanced power settings.
Under "Processor power management" you can configure the Minimum / Maximum power states and if the power management is active or passive.

Hi. It doesn't seem to work. I know the processor power min/max settings there in the Control Panel, always zeroing the minimum, and it worked for me back in the day on an older Intel CPU, but now it doesn't help.
